# BigQuery different behavior of Auto-detect vs Manual schema

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a CSV file in a Google bucket. I am trying to read this through BigQuery, hence I am creating an External Table on the CSV file. The first column of this CSV file is in the format "2022-05-14 08:00:00 Africa/Accra".

When I use Auto-detect schema, I can query the file, while when I manually define the same schema as the auto-detected one, I get an error: "Could not parse '2022-05-14 08:00:00 Africa/Accra' as TIMESTAMP for field SMS_DT (position 0) starting at location 415 with message 'Unrecognized timezone: Africa/Accra'".

How is that difference justified? How can I still manually define the schema with successful results?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, thanks for your answer but I do not see how it is useful. I can manually define the schema through the UI, so what difference would it make to define it programmatically?

Comment: Hi @Stathis, since I have manually defined the schema in code and given auto-detect option, I am able to successfully insert `2022-05-14 08:00:00 Africa/Accra`. You can also try `insert into project.dataset.table values('2022-05-14 08:00:00 Africa/Accra')`.

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar, I am a bit confused: is the schema defined? or auto-detected? I see you have set both.

Comment: HI @Stathis, I have made the changes as per your requirement. Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: @Stathis were you able to resolve this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to manually define the schema, you can use the  [Python Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) in which you can define the schema.You can set `autodetect=False` when you explicitly specify the schema of the table. You can try the below code for your reference.

**Code:**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
 
# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()
 
# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
table_id = "project.dataset.tablename"
 
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
 
    schema = [
        
        bigquery.SchemaField("E", "DATETIME"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("F", "INTEGER"),
        bigquery.SchemaField("G", "TIMESTAMP")
    ],
    autodetect=False,
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
)
uri = "gs://bucket/sample.csv"
 
load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.
 
load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.
 
destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

**Sample.csv**

```
E,F,G
2021-01-12 23:26:37,986,2022-05-14 08:00:00 Africa/Accra
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some subtle difference when BigQuery loads source files using auto-detect schema and when we manually create schema and load source files into table.

Even I faced this issue where when I tried loading file from BigQuery console it was loaded without any issues but when I used the same schema and tried to load the same file through Python Client; it raised parsing errors.

So, the easier workaround was to use STRING datatype for the columns causing errors and then use E.g. PARSE_DATETIME/ PARSE_TIMESTAMP function to parse string data.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#parse_datetime

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', '2022-05-14 08:00:00 Africa/Accra')
```